# Delete duplicates from a huge table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing, delete-row

I have an unusual problem: I need to delete duplicate records from a table in Postgresql. As i have duplicate records so i dont have primary key and unique index in this table. The table conatins like 20million records and it has duplicate records in it. While i am trying the below query it is taking too long time.

'DELETE FROM temp a using temp b where a.recordid=b.recordid and a.ctid < b.ctid;'

So what should be a better approach to handle such huge table with no index in it?
Appreciate for help.

Comment: Create a non-unique index on (recordid, ctid). Then run the same query. BTW 20 million rows is not a huge table, it is barely large if even that.

Answer (score 1):

if you have enough empty space, your can copy table without duplicates, then remove old table and rename new table

like this

```
INSERT INTO new_table
VALUES
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (column) 
  *
FROM old_table
ORDER BY column ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COPY TO` to dump the table.

Then Unix `sort -u` to de-duplicate it.

Drop or truncate the table in Postgres, use `COPY FROM` to read it back in.

Add a primary key column.